# Using pd.Grouper with multiple time units (months, days)

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am grouping data by timestamps, and only need to do one unit, so this code works for me to group by every 3 months:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq=3M) columns=['foo1', 'foo2'], values='value')
```

However, would it be possible to group by 2 different time units? For example, 3 months and 5 days? I imagined it as looking like below...

```
pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='3M 5D')
```

This doesn't work though. Is there an elegant pandas solution here?

Edit: Providing some starting code. It just has one column instead of foo1, foo2 but it should be fine like that.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp' : [
                    Timestamp('2017-01-01 12:00:00'),
                    Timestamp('2017-02-06 12:00:00'),
                    Timestamp('2017-03-11 12:00:00'),
                    Timestamp('2017-04-16 12:00:00'),
                    Timestamp('2017-05-01 12:00:00'),
                    Timestamp('2017-06-18 12:00:00'),
                    Timestamp('2017-07-01 12:00:00'),
                    ],
    'values': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    'cols': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'blah', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']}
    )
    
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='3M'), columns='cols', values='values')
```

The answer to this question would be to pivot this data by 3 months 5 days, or some arbitrary combination of time units

Comment: Please, can you provide a minimal sample to be usable with your pivot.

Comment: Sure thing I added some code that just makes a df and pivot's it.

Comment: Unfortunately I think it's not possible but you can try something. Use `pd.date_range` to create a datetime index with a freq of 3M and add N*5 days (N=0 for the first date, N=1 for the second date, and so on). Then, use `pd.cut` to set your dates in the right interval. Now `pivot` with this new index. I'll try tomorrow if I can.

Comment: I see, thanks for the idea. If you're busy don't worry about it. This post was for curiosity I don't really need it solved